# Не загружается ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, grub

На жестком диске у меня есть две ОС: Windows и Ubuntu. Все было нормально. Запускалось то и то. Через grub было видно две системы. Сидел через ubuntu, выключил ноутбук. На следующий день включаю, в grub выбираю загрузить ubuntu и появляется вот такое что на фото.[image]

```
/dev/sda6 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.
/dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda6 requires a manual fsck.
```

Comment: там же написано: файловая система, созданная внутри раздела `/dev/sda6`, повреждена. и предлагается запустить `fsck -y /dev/sda6`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вроде все написано 
Ошибка файловой системы 
Запустите fsck в ручном режиме

Comment: `fsck -y /dev/sda6` прописал эту команду и все ок. спасибо

Answer (score 4):

Ошибки файловой системы не дают возможности загрузиться.

Для того чтобы проверить раздел, при невозможности загрузки системы:

1. В grub выберите 'Ubuntu (recovery mode)' (обычно следует за пунктом загрузки самой системы, или в подменю).
2. Должно появиться синее меню, в котором выберете fsck

Если recovery mode также не загружается - надо будет использовать livecd для проверки файловой системы.